# How to override event URL in Facebook pixel

Tags: facebook, pixel, facebook-pixel

Does anyone know how we can change the event URL(Pixel Location) in Facebook pixel?
I have a couple of pages on my website that contains personal information as a query string(PII), as you better know it's forbidden to send PII information to Facebook. Recently I received a warning from Facebook to stop collecting PII. Since this information is being collected automatically from the page URL I don't know to override this URL:

[image]

[image]

In Facebook conversion API we can make it by adding "event_source_url" please help me with client-side pixel.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can override it but the only possible way that I've tried and actually worked [no script tag debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YXBw.jpg) is to use the NoScript FB pixel instead, for this particular case since you are using the conversions API, I think you can add the event ID for the deduplication, once done, you have to remove the JS pixel counterpart, that's the fix I found for now.